# biblatex what is the delimiter between author and title in the bibliography for verbose-inote

Tags: biblatex, delimiters

I would like to add a comma and space as the delimiter between the author key and the title key for entries in the bibliography, I am using verbose-inote as the biblatex style. I tried, without success:

```
\renewcommand*{\nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

I can't find the right delimiter in the

> 3.11 Formatting Commands

and

> 3.11.1 Generic Commands and Hooks

sections of the biblatex documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nametitledelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter and should be redefined with `\DeclareDelimFormat`. In the bibliography context `bib`, `nametitledelim` falls back to `\labelnamepunct` (which in turn is `\newunitpunct` by default) for backwards compatibility reasons, so you have to explicitly redefine `nametitledelim` in the `bib` context if you want to affect the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]